# Take values from SQL string with regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two strings

```
left join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;
```

what i want from first string:

```
=> left join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid
=> right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid 
=> join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid
```

second string:

```
join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid group by id;
```

what i want from second string:

```
=> join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid
=> right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid
=> join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid
```

That's what i did... but it's not working properly...

```
/([inner|left|right|full]*?\s.+?(?:inner|left|right|full|join|;))/
```

Comment: Stop that, it's a waste of time for a bad result, and use an SQL parser, try something like: https://github.com/cryodex/sql-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While attempting to parse SQL using regular expressions is impossible in general, for this specific example you can try:

`/(((inner|left|right|full)\s+)?join\s+[^=]*=\s*\S+\b)/`

```
> regexp = /(((inner|left|right|full)\s+)?join\s+[^=]*=\s*\S+\b)/

> str1 = "left join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;"
 => "left join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid;"

> str1.scan(regexp).map(&:first)
 => ["left join orderitem on order.id = orderitem.orderid", "right join product on product.id = orderitem.productid", "join orders on customers.customerid=orders.customerid"]
```

Answer (score 2):

So I am not sure if you just want a solution or one that fits what you have already tried??

I found the following provided the desired output:

```
/(.*?= ?[^ ;]*) ?/
```

If you need a solution using your current regex option I might need longer to work it out :)

Comment: also for other people stumbling across this answer, you can use [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) to test your regular expressions. Here's the examples from the questions along with the solution: http://regexr.com/3f611

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the other answers, using regular expressions may not be the best approach.

There are SQL parsers for Ruby that you can use like [sql-parser](https://github.com/cryodex/sql-parser)

Using it, it would be easy to parse your strings.

In the code for sql-parser you can see that it [knows how to parse different types of JOIN statements](https://github.com/cryodex/sql-parser/blob/master/lib/sql-parser/parser.racc#L99)